# Gallery with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, gallery

I have following problem have to make image gallery that changing pictures after some delay but also user to have option to enter other delay in field and via button to set new delay.I manage to do 1st part with gallery with default delay but having problems with 2nd part where must get new data from field and set is with button.Here some of the code

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    var speed="200";//Slide show speed
       setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, speed);
   });
</script>



<script>
   $(function delay()
   {
      document.getElementById("delay").value=document.setElementById("var speed").value;
   }
</script>

<button id="slide" type="button" onclick="setdelay()">Click Me!</button>
<input type="delay" id="delay">
```

Comment: the second script tag is invalid the last character should be a closing bracket ie. ), there are a multitude of mistakes with this, the onclcik to trigger the function setdelay(), you have not specified the function for,

Comment: There is no element shown with the id of `var speed`(also white space isn't allowed in id's so that's invalid). Also if we're already using jQuery why not change `document.getElementById("delay").value=document.setElementById("var speed").value;` `$('#delay').val($('#var-speed').val())`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need something like this:

```
<script>
   $(function delay()
   {
      speed = document.getElementById("delay").value;
      setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, speed);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: `$(function delay()` should be `function delay()